# Animating (drawing) a Squigly Line using CSS / SVG

Tags: css, animation, svg

Okay so I have a line animation I would like to do which looks like this:

[image]

I want to be able to animate the line so it appears from the top left and then finishes at the bottom right.

From researching, I see a good way to do this is using stroke offset but I don't understand how this would work with a shape as I have...

The code I have at the moment is as follows (but this is nothing like what I want to do...

```css
    .path {
      stroke-dasharray: 1000;
      stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
      animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
      from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 822;
      }
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 973 728">

    <g transform="translate(0.000000,728.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
    <path class="path" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-width="24" d="M1316 7271 c5 -5 65 -55 134 -112 297 -247 621 -598 812 -880 297
    -438 428 -863 378 -1224 -13 -91 -41 -207 -49 -203 -3 2 -51 29 -106 60 -679
    388 -1569 407 -2091 46 -88 -60 -215 -192 -263 -271 -41 -71 -76 -155 -103
    -255 -17 -61 -21 -106 -21 -217 0 -123 3 -151 27 -230 15 -49 38 -114 52 -142
    122 -252 365 -432 654 -484 94 -16 289 -14 400 5 132 24 313 86 455 157 380
    191 831 585 1032 901 l55 88 41 -35 c57 -49 170 -177 224 -255 62 -87 155
    -266 193 -370 81 -218 106 -396 115 -805 23 -1064 245 -1859 669 -2389 384
    -481 968 -709 1651 -646 521 48 1076 234 1845 617 555 276 919 503 1424 889
    223 171 577 514 761 739 137 168 125 134 125 357 l0 193 -23 -40 c-110 -193
    -305 -433 -542 -671 -413 -414 -891 -765 -1502 -1100 -700 -384 -1339 -640
    -1833 -733 -242 -45 -533 -58 -730 -32 -883 117 -1420 845 -1585 2146 -30 236
    -45 461 -45 670 0 443 -56 739 -195 1032 -97 205 -205 355 -377 525 l-118 116
    25 89 c44 152 58 267 53 452 -4 120 -11 195 -28 271 -106 497 -423 1007 -942
    1515 -89 88 -182 177 -206 198 l-42 37 -167 0 c-95 0 -163 -4 -157 -9z m286
    -2286 c223 -29 443 -94 648 -191 105 -50 260 -139 260 -150 0 -2 -24 -44 -54
    -92 -184 -297 -614 -672 -969 -846 -205 -100 -382 -146 -564 -146 -227 0 -397
    70 -538 223 -112 121 -165 260 -165 438 0 402 305 680 839 764 119 18 404 18
    543 0z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: You have a filled path. What it should be is a simple line path with a wide stroke.

Comment: Ah okay, so you mean the line should be 1px width? Then I use the stroke to create the animation?

Comment: The path will have no actual width until you apply a stroke but essentially yes.

Comment: Something like this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jOMgmRQ

Comment: @Paulie_D - Looks awesome, but does this affect only work with full shapes or can it work with the shape I posted in the original question?

Comment: It will work with any non-filled path. Whether or not the path is closed. The secret is the Path Length attribute. Otherwise you need to know the actual path length.